# GUI and main code running in main thread with Matlab, no PyQt5 equivalent?

Tags: python, multithreading, matlab, user-interface, pyqt5

I have a project involving a graphical interface and a main code. I develop the project on both Matlab and Python. In the project, the graphical interface collects information from the user, and then this information is used in the main code. Ideally, the interface pops first, waits for the user to provide information, then the main code is run with the information while the interface is still opened but remains idle. In Matlab, this is done trivially, as shown by the following minimal example (simplified version of what I want to do).

first file: GraphicalUserInterface.m

```
classdef GraphicalUserInterface < handle

    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess= public)
        interface
        pushbutton
        wait
    end

    methods (Access = public)
    
        function self = GrapicalUserInterface()
            self.wait = true;
        end
    
        function launch_interface(self)
            % main window
            self.interface = figure();
            set(self.interface, 'units', 'pixels', 'position', [100 100 200 200]);
            % pushbutton
            self.pushbutton = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton');
            set(self.pushbutton, 'unit', 'pixels', 'position', [50 50 100 100]);
            set(self.pushbutton, 'String', 'stop waiting');
            set(self.pushbutton, 'CallBack', @self.callback); 
        end
    
        function callback(self, hObject, callbackdata)
            self.wait = false;       
        end
    
    end        

end
```

second file: main.m

```
clear
clc

% create gui
gui = GraphicalUserInterface();
gui.launch_interface;

% wait for user to be done with gui (gui.wait becomes 'false')
waitfor(gui, 'wait');

% run main code (here just some dummy code to verify everything works)
x = 2;
y = x + 3;
disp(y);
```

The 'GraphicalUserInterface' class defines the interface, the 'main' script runs the main code. 'main' first calls for the interface, then pauses execution with 'waitfor'. Whenever the single pushbutton of the interface is pressed, the attribute 'wait' is switched to false and waitfor terminates, thus allowing the main code to run. The interface remains opened and can be used again once the main code is processed. Also, I can still use the prompt and run other scripts while the interface is opened.

With Python, the equivalent would be given by the following codes, using PyQt5:

first file: GraphicalUserInterface.m

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class GraphicalUserInterface: 

    def __init__(self):
        self.wait = True
    
    def launch_interface(self):
        # main window
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.interface = QMainWindow()
        self.interface.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        # pushbutton
        self.pushbutton = QPushButton(self.interface)
        self.pushbutton.move(50, 50)                                             
        self.pushbutton.resize(100, 100)
        self.pushbutton.setText('stop waiting')
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.callback)
        # display interface
        self.interface.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
    
    def callback(self):    
        self.wait = False
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.start()


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        # run main code (here just some dummy code to verify everything works)
        x = 2
        y = x + 3
        print(y)
```

second file: main.py

```
from GraphicalUserInterface import *

# create gui
gui = GraphicalUserInterface()
gui.launch_interface()
```

The code is slightly different from Matlab. Because PyQt5 runs on the main thread only, I have to use multithreading and run the main code from the Worker class, as is usually done with PyQt5.

Even though the two codes may look equivalent, they differ in important aspects.

1. With Matlab, the main code runs in the main thread. Thus anything is done in the global space and can be accessed after the main code is completed (e.g. the x and y variables). With Python, everything runs within the Worker class, itself run within the GraphicalUserInterface. Thus the main code runs in a local space only, and nothing is saved in the global space (e.g. x and y have no existence in the global space). This is  not acceptable for my project, I need to access everything in the global space.
2. At the margin: creating the GUI with Python keeps the main thread busy in the GUI loop, so nothing else can be done within the main thread / python prompt. Creating another thread is necessary to run anything else. On the other hand, Matlab is perfectly happy with having a GUI opened and at the same time keeping your main thread available for additional instructions. How is this possible? I mean, I read everywhere that keeping the main thread busy with the GUI loop is absolutely necessary with GUIs, on pretty much every programming language and applications. Yet Matlab is clear evidence that it isn't true, and that you can run a GUI while still keeping your main thread available.

So my two questions are:

1. Is there a way to have a GUI with PyQt5 and then run your main code in the main thread also, so that everything is created in the global space and that the results can be accessed after the main code is over?
   At worst, is there a way to run the main code from a second thread but still have the results/variables generated available in the global space afterwards? At the moment, the only option I can think would be to create the GUI, programmatically close it once info is collected, run the main code, then open the GUI again once the main code is completed. But really, can't we do better than that?
2. How can we explain the difference of behaviour between Python and Matlab, the latter being obviously much more flexible and permissive?

Sorry for the long post, thanks a lot to anyone who may contribute to this discussion.

Comment: There are different levels and perceptions of "flexible and permissive". From what I can see, Matlab is both of them in a very bad way. That said, is your requirement to update the UI with the result of the worker thread? Note that a QThread (as much as a python Thread) doesn't work by adding the computetion in the `__init__`, but in its `run()` method.

Comment: Hi Musicamante,
thanks for your comment. No, updating the GUI with the result of the worker thread is not a requirement. What is a requirement however is that I can access the results of the Worker thread in the global space after the Worker is done.

Comment: as Tim already suggested, the concept of global is generally frown upon for OO programming, and Python is not an exception. Matlab is a very specific programming language, with its own structures and conventions that work well for its purposes. But if you step into Python (or almost any other language), you cannot try to use the same structures and conventions, as they most probably won't work well, or could even work *very badly*. You must adapt your requirements by understanding those of the language/pattern you're going to use.

Comment: Your use of the class in the MATLAB code just complicates things. You could have written a simple function to construct your UI. I also find your use of a UI as a gate (all you do is wait for a button press) weird. Just use a call to `msgbox`, or a simple `pause`. The normal way is to run specific code as the callback, not just allow the main program to continue.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: as I said, this is a very simplified version of what my GUI is actually doing. I reduced it here to a single button to make my point: how a Matlab GUI can trigger an event that terminates the pause and switches back to the main code. Also, as my actual GUI is much more complex than that, it makes sense to use a class as it makes the whole stuff cleaner. As for running the code in a callback, as I mentioned, it creates problem since everything is then created locally. I need to run a main code to have my results creates globally, and possibly accessed later by the user.

Comment: There’s a difference between global and base workspace variables. Your results live in the base workspace, and are accessible only from the base workspace, not globally. You can use `assignin` in your GUI callback to put variables in the base workspace so they’re  accessible from your user’s scripts. But it’s better practice to return those variables from the function that creates the GUI. Explicit assignment of values is better than “magically appearing” variables.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: wow, I didn't know about assignin. That's very useful indeed, and corresponds to what I am looking for. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run all code in the main thread in PyQt if you use use the `asyncio` event loop. For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import qasync
import asyncio

class GraphicalUserInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wait = True

    def launch_interface(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.interface = QMainWindow()
        self.interface.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.pushbutton = QPushButton(self.interface)
        self.pushbutton.move(50, 50)
        self.pushbutton.resize(100, 100)
        self.pushbutton.setText('stop waiting')
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.callback)
        self.interface.show()

    def set_future(self, future):
        self.future = future

    def callback(self):
        self.future.set_result('button clicked')


class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        x = 2
        y = x + 3
        print(y)

async def worker_loop(ui):
    i = 0
    while True:
        future = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
        ui.set_future(future)
        result = await future
        Worker()
        i += 1
        if i == 4:
            break
    print("Done")

def main():
    ui = GraphicalUserInterface()
    ui.launch_interface()
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(ui.app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    with loop:
        loop.run_until_complete(worker_loop(ui))

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

All GUI frameworks use a dedicated message dispatch loop.  Matlab is just hiding that loop from you.  Matlab runs with a more layers of abstraction that Python and Qt, so you just don't notice it.  It looks convenient, but it means you overlook practices that are dangerous.

Matlab has always encouraged poor programming practices.  Everything is a global, functions are awkward, scoping rules are lax.  You can be productive, but anything larger than a few dozen lines it totally unmaintainable.

Your comments about Python's global space are wrong.  For example, if you put `globals x, y` at the beginning of `Worker.__init__`, then you would be able to access them globally, but that's terrible coding practice.  In an object-oriented language, you need to think about your objects.  What state do you have?  Which objects should hold that state?  Which state needs to be shared?  How should it be accessed?  Matlab doesn't make you think about that, which results in bad code.

The rule with GUIs is that the message loop must run in the same thread where the windows are created.  The originating thread must process the messages.  In the vast majority of cases, that thread is the main thread, and some frameworks do make that assumption, but it's not required.

However, I encourage you to learn to do things the right way.  Concepts that work in Matlab don't make for good Python code, even if they work.  So, put your GUI code in the main thread, and handle things by responding to events.  Through your computationally intensive code into a thread.  You will get a better application as a result.

Comment: Dear Tim,
thanks for your comments. However, I don't understand why my comments on Python global space are wrong. I am well aware that you can use global statements to access variables globally, but as you say, this is terrible practice. Also, with a code producing dozens of different variables, global is just unmanageable. So in the end, if you just use things as I describe them (Worker within GUI class), then you do work locally only and the results of your worker won't appear in the global space.

Comment: I understand that 'good practice' supposes you run your main code in a separate thread, and that your GUI is in the main thread. Fine, I have no ideological problem with that. I have however a requirement, which is that once the main code is run, eveyrthing should be available n the global space so that my app users can recover any result/data of interest. With a separate thread, I don't see how it's possible (except again using global statements which are terrible and not an option in my case).

Comment: @RomainLegrand You're still thinking in concepts of "global space". Forget about that. If you have an app, then it will be the *app space*, which will probably be an instance of a class. Then you can use Qt signals to communicate from the worker thread and notify the app (or the UI or whatever the app uses to interact with the user) about any changes in its values.

Comment: @musicamante: I see what you are trying to say, and understand the argument. I have myself designed such apps with signals communicating with the GUI in the past, and am well aware that it is the normal way to do things. However, if I stick to the global space now, it is because I have good reasons to do so. To be explicit: I design an econometric app that will produce a number of elements (mostly numpy arrays, lists and dictionnaries containing score values).

Comment: Users of my App will typically want to access those results to use them as a basis for further calculations, analysis, and possibly complex statistical applications. Hence, there is no way around, those results HAVE TO be available once the main code has run. And since I don't known in advance which precise elements will be of interest for a given user, everything should just be freely, directly and easily available. With apps/signals, I don't see how this can be achieved.

Comment: @RomainLegrand that would have been an important aspect you should have explained in your question. Without those elements it's hard to understand what your is your actual requirement and if there are possible solutions. From what you're describing, I'd consider using a class that acts as a "container" for those elements and generate a unique object instance of that class that could then be used to access all the elements. In *that* case, you won't be using "globals" (plurals), but a unique shared object that, while globally accessible, can be safely and properly implemented.

Comment: @musicamante: thanks for the complement. Yes you're right, I should have been more explicit about my requirements from the start. Now that it is more clear, your solution becomes quite handy. I would still like to see if a possibly simpler solution can be found for this specific issue. Anyway, thanks very much for your time and suggestions.

Comment: I don’t at all agree with any of your characterization of MATLAB. It does allow bad coding practices, but it certainly doesn’t encourage them. You have to explicitly make a variable global. Functions are totally normal and comparable to functions in other languages. Scoping rules are clear and well defined, and not very different from Python. I’d say they are less lax than Python’s. It is clear to me you have never done more than write scripts in MATLAB, if at all. Please refrain from criticizing a tool you don’t know.

Comment: It is true that it is possible to write well-structured code in Matlab, but in my experience almost no one does so.  The same is true of PHP.  In a sense, that's not a surprise.  The tool is not aimed at professional programmers.